# i want to combine fcm response with another response

Tags: php

{
    "success":1,"Data":{"status":"message sent",
                        "message_id":3594,
                        "personaluid":"161",
                        "gid":"0",
                        "uid":"160",
                        "message":"cxzczxczxsada123",
                        "chat_image":"",
                        "created_at":"2017-02-04 16:52:11",
                        "utype":"1"
                    }
}
{
     aps = 
          {alert =
             {body = hdhd; title=from some person name;};
              badge = 1;
          };
         "gcm.message_id" = "0:1487247942837269%19aca14d19aca14d";
         "gcm.notification.Content_available" = 1; 
         "gcm.notification.created_at" = "2017-02-16 17:55:41";
         "gcm.notification.uid" = 161; 
}

Comment: what should be the result?

Comment: use array_merge

Comment: If you show the code that you use to get these 2 responses, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your json data to php array then use array_merge to merge both. Then again convert it to json data. Example:

```
 <?php
   $json1='{"success":1,
  "Data":{"status":"message sent","message_id":3594,"personaluid":"161","gid":"0","uid":"160","message":"cxzczxczxsada123","chat_image":"","created_at":"2017-02-04 16:52:11","utype":"1"}
}';
$json2='{
    "multicast_id":5114850183838817498,
    "success":1,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[{"message_id":"0:1487247086404626%19aca14d19aca14d"}]
}';

$ar1=json_decode($json1,true);
$ar2=json_decode($json2,true);
$ar1=array_merge($ar1,$ar2);
echo json_encode($ar1);
```

output:

```
{"success":1,"Data":{"status":"message sent","message_id":3594,"personaluid":"161","gid":"0","uid":"160","message":"cxzczxczxsada123","chat_image":"","created_at":"2017-02-04 16:52:11","utype":"1"},"multicast_id":5.1148501838388e+18,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1487247086404626%19aca14d19aca14d"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could array merge the 2 decoded arrays.

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);
$data = array_merge($data[0], $data[1]);
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECTS);`
```